# MS Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK - Update entity record using late-binding

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm-2011

does anyone know how to save changes to a late-bound entity using the SDK for Dynamics CRM 2011?

This is what I've tried:

```
// retrieve and modify a pet...
// (This part works)
Guid findId = new Guid("6CA57D73-30CC-E111-B155-00505630052F");
ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "name", "foodtype" });

// try to retrieve
// (this also works)
pet = xrm.Retrieve("pet", findId, attributes);
if( pet!=null )
{
    Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Retrieved pet {0} successfully!", pet["name"].ToString() ));
    // update attributes
    pet["foodtype"] = "Seaweed";
    // (from here doesn't seem to work)
    // save pet
    xrm.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine( "Done!" );
}
```

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
pet["foodtype"] = "Seaweed";

xrm.UpdateObject( pet );
xrm.SaveChanges();
```

EDIT: `"The context is not currently tracking the 'pet' entity"` means the object you get from `Retrieve` is not attached to the service context. There's a method `Attach` that does just that.

```
xrm.Attach( pet );
pet["foodtype"] = "Seaweed";

xrm.UpdateObject( pet );
xrm.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This gives an error on UpdateObject: "The context is not currently tracking the 'pet' entity".

Comment: I'd already found a solution (see below) but your answer was educational, and it works, so I'm accepting yours. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
pet["foodtype"] = "Seaweed";
pet.EntityState = EntityState.Changed; // not sure if this is really needed
// save pet
xrm.Update(pet);
```